# Google App Engine Search API, Searching DateField value before certain date

Tags: google-app-engine, google-search-api

With Google App Engine, using Search API Documents and Index, where Documents have DateField named "updated", how it is possible to query for Documents updated before 2014-05-13T00:00:00Z ?
I tried

```
query = 'updated < %s' % (mydate)
```

So the value is
    'updated < 2014-05-13T17:21:35.499000'
and it results in 
    QueryError: Failed to parse query "updated < 2014-05-13T17:21:35.499000"

Something is wrong with my syntax, but I don't know of any reference to the syntax of search API queries. Whatever little I could understand looking at the source of c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\search\QueryLexer.py, seems comparisons are allowed. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only filter using a date, not a datetime (see "Special treatment of string and date fields" [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/#Python_Documents_and_fields)). As follows:

```
query = 'updated < %s' % mydate.date()
```

The query documentation is [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/query_strings).

Comment: Yes, I found that. What confused me is that you CAN use datetime to store a field, but not a datetime STRING to search for it.

Comment: At the moment we're just storing our datetimes as ISO8601 strings in AtomFields... and then it basically works

Comment: @NickFranceschina, I am also facing issue with querying last_updated_date > last_login_date.. I want to filter based on datetime. Can you please suggest how did you use AtomFields and ISO8601 string

Comment: @VikramShinde - just google for "ISO 8601" to understand the format... then store/query on that as a normal string in an AtomField

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Answer (score 0):

approval_date here is actually an Atom field. Still it isn't working.

```
query = approval_date < olderTimeInISO8601
```

There must be another way to do it.